# Question About Amp Limitations

Tags: amperage

I recently built a device which needs to be charged using a standard 12v adapter and a certain number of amperes. I was told the adapter needed to be at least 3A to charge the device. So my question is can I use any number of amperes as long as it's greater than 3A, for instance a 12v 5A adapter? I just need to know if using more amperes than the needed amount is fine, or if it can be harmful at all. Thank you

Comment: you built an electronic device, yet you appear to know nothing about electric current.

Comment: This is unanswerable, as it depends if the charge regulation is internal to the device, or if the device expects the supply to limit the charge current to what is appropriate for the pack in its current state of charge.  Since the question does not specify this, no valid answer can be proposed.